# CoreLocation on iOS to only monitor location changes in the background for a set amount of time?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm currently writing an iOS app which needs to monitor the user's location for about 30 minutes in the background.  For this, I'm using the *Significant Change Location Service* provided by the CoreLocation API, and calling `startSignificantChangeUpdate,` and also implementing `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`.

The problem is after 30 minutes, I want to turn off the *Significant Change Location Service* and can't seem to find a way to do so.  I've got some code in `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` which checks if the location has been published for more than 30 minutes and if it has, turns it off.  The problem is that if the user is relatively immobile and the app is in the background, the location service would not be turnd off after the 30 minutes e.g. if the user has arrived home and asleep and thus won't open the app again till morning.

I've tried using the `NSTimer` class, but that seems to stop running once the app is put into the background.

I have put the 30 minute check when the application becomes active though, but then again, if the user doesn't open the app for a long time the location service could be running all night.

Apart from that I'm out of ideas on how to stop the service?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no real good way to run a timer for the background services. The good news is the last location holds a timestamp you can compare last update to. It may not be approximate times, but you should be able to disable the location services after the last update after 30 minutes.

Comment: Yep, but unfortunately the only way to get the location is to trigger an even by moving to another location and not if the user is stationary

Comment: Yes, you are right. The user will still need to move before you will be able to disable location services. Thankfully, the significant change monitoring is very low power, so you shouldn't impact battery life all that much. Good luck.